# SSH version RHL 7.7

Tags: linux, ssh, security

I have received a pentest report and one thing that i need to upgrade is the OpenSSH and OpenSSL on my Red Hat Linux 7.7 server. In the report it's mentioned that the version of SSH is:

```
ssh -v
OpenSSH_6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1q 3 Dec 2015
```

When I checck like:

```
sshd -V

OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

or

```
yum list installed openssh\*
```

Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.

Installed Packages

```
openssh.x86_64                                                                              7.4p1-21.el7                                                                      @prd-rhel-7

openssh-clients.x86_64                                                                     7.4p1-21.el7                                                                      @prd-rhel-7

openssh-server.x86_64                                                                      7.4p1-21.el7                                                                      @prd-rhel-7
```

So i'm a little bit confused about which is actually the version of OpenSSH on my server.

Can someone maybe explain me which is my version, the one returned by `ssh -v` or the one returned by `sshd -v`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On a sample RHEL 7.7 host I checked, `ssh -V` and `sshd -V` both return the same version, `OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017`.

If when you run `ssh -V` on the target server you get differing results then I would say either you have additional SSH binaries in your path (`which ssh` will show you where they are) or someone has replaced the original client binaries, (`rpm -V openssh-clients` will show you if the files don't tally with what the RPM database thinks they should be).

Otherwise I would ask for clarification as to how the version of SSH has been ascertained.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. This answer is correct. You can also check your server version by running `telnet localhost 22`. Overall, you should be worried that when you run `ssh -V` that you get different version than `sshd`.

Comment: I think the author of a now-deleted answer decided to retaliate for my downvoting of their answer as not useful. Ho-hum.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `ssh -v` it's show the version of the ssh command that you use to connect with other machines.

On the other hand, `sshd` is the daemon that allow the connections to your machine.

You can see that the libreries for each command are different:

```
$ which ssh
/usr/bin/ssh
```

And:

```
$ which sshd
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

Also, you can check the command that the `sshd` service are running:

```
$ systemctl status sshd
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
[...]

$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service
[...]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $OPTIONS
[...]
```

You can try to list all the packages and you can see the version of each `openssh` packages.

```
$ rpm -qa | grep ssh
openssh-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64
openssh-server-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64
openssh-clients-7.4p1-21.el7.x86_64
libssh2-1.8.0-3.el7.x86_64
```

If you have different version you could try to update it:

```
$ sudo yum update openssh openssh-server openssh-clients
```